# inner radius polar Highcharter

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm trying to change the inner radius of a polar chart using `highcharter` so I can visualize the data by hoving the tooltip like in this awesome `D3` charts from [`fivethirtyeight`](https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/world-cup-comparisons/).

I know that it's possible to visualize data with `solid gauge` like in [this](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-activity/dark-unica) example, but I want to the data to be visible in a `polar`.

I've tried changing `innerSize` and `innerRadius` parameters but I'm not able to accomplish it.

Here's my `R` code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)
highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(polar = T, type = "bar") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Athlete 1 vs Athlete 2") %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = c("Total Score", "Avg. Score", "Sum Score",
                          "Best Score"),
           tickmarkPlacement = "on",
           plotLines = list(
             list(label = list(
               rotation = 90))
             )
           ) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(min = 0) %>% 
  hc_series(
    list(
      name = "Athlete 1",
      data = c(43000, 19000, 60000, 35000)
    ),
    list(
      name = "Athlete 2",
      data = c(50000, 39000, 42000, 31000)
    )
  ) %>% 
  hc_colors(c("firebrick", "steelblue"))
```

---

The desired output would be something like:
[image]

Thank you!

---

### EDIT

After @ppotaczek's answer I've updated with his chart, so the desired updated would look like this:

[image]

Comment: @ewolden Thank you! This is similar, but not what I want since it's a pie chart. If you take a look at the fivethirtyeight link you'll see the data from the chart inside the pane.

Comment: I can do the polar chart... If you execute my `R` code you'll see. But I'm not able to get the data to be visible inside the chart pane like in the fivethirtyeight example.

Comment: Okay, then I am not sure. I am familiar with highcharts, not with R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve similar result in Highcharts polar chart, you should set **pointPadding** and **groupPadding** to 0. To create an empty space in the middle of the graph you can use Highcharts.SVGRenderer and **offset** for yAxis.

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'bar',
        events: {
            render: function() {
                var chart = this,
                    middleElement = chart.middleElement;

                if (middleElement) {
                    middleElement.destroy();
                }

                chart.middleElement = chart.renderer.circle(chart.plotSizeX / 2 + chart.plotLeft, chart.plotHeight / 2 + chart.plotTop, 20).attr({
                    zIndex: 3,
                    fill: '#ffffff'
                }).add();
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        offset: 20
    },

    series: [{
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0,
        name: "Athlete 1",
        data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000]
    }, {
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0,
        name: "Athlete 2",
        data: [50000, 39000, 42000, 31000]
    }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y6uL180j/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#circle

**EDIT:**
To display value from hovered point in the middle of the chart, use tooltip with proper options:

```
tooltip: {
    borderWidth: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'none',
    shadow: false,
    style: {
        fontSize: '16px'
    },
    headerFormat: '',
    pointFormatter: function() {
        return this.y / 1000 + 'k'
    },
    positioner: function(labelWidth, labelHeight) {
        return {
            x: (this.chart.plotSizeX - labelWidth) / 2 + this.chart.plotLeft,
            y: (this.chart.plotSizeY - labelHeight) / 2 + this.chart.plotTop
        };
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5ybhtrmz/

Comment: Thank you! I guess my question was unclear. I've added an image based on the chart you've sent with the only think missing in the desired output. Thank you!

Comment: Hi patL, I've edited the answer, please check the result now.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This is just what wanted!! I would vote up your answer 10 times!

Comment: Just saw the [`valueSuffix`](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/split/) parameter, so you can add the `k` in the tooltip suffix.